# How do I convert a boolean from true/false to yes/no on a Telerik ASP .NET MVC Grid

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, telerik

I would like to be able to change the display value of a non-editable column on a non-editable Telerik AJAX grid in ASP.NET MVC. The column in question is a boolean value sot the display conversion would be Yes=true and No-False.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a little experimenting and found this works. Not sure if it will hold up on an editable column but in my case the column is not editable.

```
<% Html.Telerik().Grid<SomeClass>()
   .Name("SomeGrid")
   .Columns(columns =>
   {
      columns.Bound(o => o.ReportingPeriodShortDescription);
      columns.Bound(o => o.Closed)
          .ClientTemplate("<#=Closed ? 'Yes' : 'No' #>")
          .Title("Closed")
          .Width("4em");
   })
   .Footer(false)
   .Render();
%>
```

Comment: Good use case for a ternary expression: `.ClientTemplate("<#= Closed ? 'Yes' : 'No' #>")`

Comment: I used `.ClientTemplate("<\\#=Closed ? 'Yes' : 'No' \\#>")` instead of  `.ClientTemplate("<#=Closed ? 'Yes' : 'No' #>")`

Answer (score 0):

Use a template to convert the value from True/False to Yes/No.  Here is an example of how to do so:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/how-do-i-show-yes-no-for-boolean-columns-instead-of-true-false.aspx

Comment: biggs, thanks for your response. I saw that answer. It lacks depth and I could not figure out how to apply it my grid definition which uses a fluent API. I actually figured out how to do it but I can't post the answer for 8 hours.

Comment: -1 For pointing to the asp.net webform grid, the question was about the asp.net mvc grid.

Answer (score 0):

I found an example on Telerik forums that walkthrough doing it based on server or client bindings.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/changing-a-bool-field-to-display-yes-no.aspx

In my case I'm using AJAX binding so I need a ClientTemplate:

```
columns.Bound(model => model.SubLimits).Title("Sublimits").Width(100)
    .ClientTemplate("<#=SubLimits?'Yes':'No'#>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for a while - In my case the < > around the expression in the ClientTemplate didn't seem to work. I spotted the problem by viewing the generated html - it was generating tags such as `<no></no>.` The following works fine for me:

```
          columns.Bound(c => c.DHSLane).Title("DHS Lane")
                 .ClientTemplate("#=DHSLane?'Yes':'No'#")
```